# Kivy: PyInstaller not including Kivy modules upon compiling spec file

Tags: module, kivy, pyinstaller

I've been following [Creating Packages for Mac OS](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-macosx.html) from Kivy.org in order to try and create a .app for my Kivy .py file.

However, despite following the guide through, my App never works, it crashes instantly upon opening. Pyinstaller's warning's concerning the build were dumped in a .txt that contained the following:

`W: no module named kivy.graphics.ClearBuffers (top-level import by kivy.uix.screenmanager)
W: no module named kivy.core.spelling.SpellingBase (top-level import by kivy.core.spelling.spelling_enchant)
W: no module named kivy.core.image.ImageLoader (top-level import by kivy.core.image.img_gif)
W: no module named multiprocessing.RLock (top-level import by multiprocessing.sharedctypes)`

and so on . . . (Full file is very long, but can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/KGJk7APn))

It seems like no kivy modules at all could be found, so they must have not been included for some reason. This is what I want to ask how to fix.

As of right now, I have been using the commands:

```
kivy pyinstaller.py myapp.py
kivy pyinstaller.py myapp.spec
```

respectively to create both the spec file and the App.
The spec file doesn't seem to have anything missing. (I've included the hooks and checked with a working spec file I used to create an .exe in the past)

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import install_hooks
install_hooks(globals())

a = Analysis(['Meep/Meep.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/Owatch/Documents/pyinstaller/Meep'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Meep',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='Meep/icon.icns')
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('/Users/Owatch/Desktop/examples/demo/touchtracer/'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='Meep')
```

Anyways, I'm not sure why this is occuring. My suspicions are mostly around the following:

**1:** I downloaded pyinstaller as a .zip since I could not find the .py file on my system. This is despite having it installed via pip on what I believe to be a separate python installation (I have 2.7 separately)

**2:** My reference to touchtracer is somehow wrong, it is linked to the touchtracer directory that came bundled in the dmg for Kivy. (A folder named Examples, which I dragged to my desktop)

Other than that, I'm afraid I'm pretty clueless. Thanks for helping (If you can!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It appears that the error was associated with a flawed spec file. Nothing else to report.**

Comment: Can you elaborate what is wrong with your spec? I have trouble in my generated spec file too (it was autogenerated, right?). This mean, I can't even package the touchtracher demo

Comment: I can't remember for sure since it's been a while. But I believe it had something to do with the process in which I was creating the spec files. I was editing spec files rather than re-creating it for changes and it wasn't working out for some procedural reason. If you're not starting the process from scratch it's probably just going to be problematic. I'm sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Okay, I manage to create the OSX *.app file from touchtracer demo, and run the application via Terminal. But,I can't double click it to run it. I still have to use Terminal. I have been fighting with this issue recently. Do your generated *.app file can be run by double clicking its icon from Finder?

Comment: Yes, they can run via the Finder. But only on the Mac I built it on. They don't or won't run on other Mac's using OSX. It's a problem I've yet to solve.

Comment: Okay, great. I can run it. Got to manually copy kivy/ folder from /Applications/Kivy.app. I will try this on other Mac. Thanks!

Comment: @swdev Be sure to check back if it does. I suspect it may be isolated to my specific application, but I'd be interested to see what you find.

Comment: It did run. Just make sure that all package were read by pyinstaller. I intentionally import packages from my main script, although it's not directly use by that main script. Well, that's my guess :)